# Xcode 8.2.1 keeps shutting down on startup

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Every time I open the IDE it starts loading then shuts down before I get a chance to change anything. Remember this happening before on previous Versions of Xcode but I haven't had to deal with this in a rally long time. Any ideas?

PS. I think its Xcode 8.2.1 ,really hard to check when it closes down immediately.

Comment: I also faced the same issue, then I delete the Xcode and install it again. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Yeah XCode 8 is really bad. All you can try to do is delete and reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that deleting **Derived Data** enabled X-code to start responding again.

Was difficult to find it though as most people were explaining how to find it from within Xcode :P If future me or any other super-devs would like to know the default directory then you can find it under the hidden folder Library on your user directory IE. **/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**

Comment: Thank past me just had this happen again :P